# Why my XCode 4.2 ask to download iOS 3.2/4.0 Simulator even though I have XCode 3.2 version installed with those simulators?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, simulator

Does different versions of XCode needs different installation of Simulators??

I mean if I have

XCode 3.2

- iOS 3.2 Simulator
- iOS 4.0 Simulator

XCode 4.0

- iOS 3.2 Simulator
- iOS 4.0 Simulator

XCode 4.2

- iOS 3.2 Simulator
- iOS 4.0 Simulator
- iOS 5.0 Simulator

Why does one simulator works for all newer versions of XCode?

Answer (score 1):

The updated XCode 4.2 simulator includes support for many previous operating system versions. The older (XCode 3.2) simulator does not include support for the newer operating system versions supported by the XCode 4.2 simulator. Therefore in order to simulate newer operating system versions you need the newer simulator.

Comment: You mean to say if I have XCode 4.1 installed having 4.1 Simulator and if I install XCode4.2 iOS 5 having Simulator 5. Then will my XCode 4.2 shows Simulator 4.1???   This is not working for me...